# Read Attribute on property without calling getter?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

C# 4.0. I have a *slow* property with an attribute. I want to read this attribute without calling the getter:

```
[Range(0.0f, 1000.0f)]
public float X
{
    get
    {
        return SlowFunctionX();
    }
}
```

This is what I have now:

```
public static T GetRangeMin<T>(T value)
{
    var attribute = value.GetType()
        .GetField(value.ToString())
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RangeAttribute), false)
        .SingleOrDefault() as RangeAttribute;

    return (T)attribute.Minimum;
}

var min = GetRangeMin<double>(X); // Will call the getter of X :(
```

**Q:** How can I read this attribute without calling the getter of `X`?

Comment: This might help..similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637679/reflection-get-attribute-name-and-value-on-property/6637710#6637710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to get it like that anyway, because you'll be calling something like `GetRangeMin<float>(0.0f)`, and the float type doesn't have a field called whatever-value-X-has.

If you want to do it in a general and type-safe way, you need to use Expressions:

```
public static T GetRangeMin<T>(Expression<Func<T>> value)
```

invoked thus:

```
var min = GetRangeMin(() => X);
```

You then need to navigate the expression tree to get the property info

```
MemberExpression memberExpression = value.Body as MemberExpression;
if (null == memberExpression || memberExpression.Member.MemberType != MemberTypes.Property)
    throw new ArgumentException("Expect a field access", "FieldExpression");
PropertyInfo propInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
```

Now you can `GetCustomAttributes` on the `propInfo`. Just as an aside, if you're worried about inheritance, you might need to use `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(propInfo, ...)` because `propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(...)` won't walk the inheritance tree even if you ask it to.

Answer (score 9):

To read the attribute on the property just load the attribute directly

```
var attrib = typeof(TheTypeContainingX)
  .GetProperty("X")
  .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RangeAttribute), false)
  .Cast<RangeAttribute>()
  .FirstOrDefault();
return attrib.Minimum;
```