# string.join/properties.select by display name instead of variable name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, entity-framework

I'm using the following code to export a table to csv using Entity Framework and MVC:

```
string header = string.Join("\t", properties.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray());
```

Is there any way to select the display name I set in my model for example displaying "Hours" instead of "hrs":

```
    [Display(Name = "Hours")]
    public float hrs { get; set;
```

Currently I just get all the variable names and not the diaplay names I set. It seems like  there should be an easy fix to this, but google isn't being much help.

Comment: Are you attempting to do this via reflection?  If so, check out the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637679/reflection-get-attribute-name-and-value-on-property

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an attribute from a Property (such as hrs) use the below method

```
    public static string GetDisplayName(Type type, string prpName)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            if(!prop.Name.Equals(prpName))
            {
                continue;
            }

            object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            foreach (object attr in attrs)
            {
                if (attr is Display)
                {
                    Display dAttr = (Display)attr;
                    return dAttr.Name;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

If you want to get it for all of them, you should produce a list and work off that.

I would suggest something like this:

```
    public static string[] GetDisplayNames(Type type)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
        string[] dNames = new string[props.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < dNames.Length; i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = props[i];
            object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            foreach (object attr in attrs)
            {
                if (attr is Display)
                {
                    Display dAttr = (Display)attr;
                    dNames[i] = dAttr.Name;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dNames[i]))
            {
                dNames[i] = prop.Name;
            }
        }

        return dNames;
    }
```

See:

- [Reflection - get attribute name and value on property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637679/reflection-get-attribute-name-and-value-on-property)
- [Get attribute values from property and list values without knowing the attribute type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076158/get-attribute-values-from-property-and-list-values-without-knowing-the-attribute?lq=1)
- [Read Attribute on property without calling getter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620600/read-attribute-on-property-without-calling-getter?lq=1)