# Can you access Scaffold attribute property of a class in C# and Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For example if you have

```
 public class user 
 {
    public string x { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string y { get; set; }
 }
```

Is there anyway, when I look at the entity to determine if y is indeed has scaffold column to false? I have tried looping through programatically like so (pseudo-code):

```
foreach(var prop in user.GetProperties())
{  
    var attributes = prop.Attributes;
}
```

but there seems to be no property attribute of the properties or to indicate weather the property (in this case y) is a scaffoldcolumn or not.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6637710/336384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the properties that have `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` like this:

```
var props = obj.GetType()
           .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
           .Select(p => new
           {
               Property = p,
               Attribute = p.GetCustomAttribute<ScaffoldColumnAttribute>()
           })
           .Where(p => p.Attribute != null && p.Attribute.Scaffold == false)
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation of 'user', 'x' and 'y' are not Properties.  Implement them as described below and they will appear in the 'GetProperties' collection

```
public class user 
{
    public string x { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string y { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: They are. Sorry, I was using pseudo code to show a proof of concept. I will update my question to reflect that.