# Change property name for client output

Tags: c#, reflection

I am writing some code that will send an email with details of what is inside the properties of a class.

Instead of hard coding the rows with the properties, I thought it was best to do this via `reflection`

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();

Type type = obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if (property.GetValue(obj, null) != null)
    {
        builder.AppendLine("<tr>");
        builder.AppendLine("<td>");

        builder.AppendLine("<b> " + property.Name + " </b>");

        builder.AppendLine("</td>");
        builder.AppendLine("<td>");

        builder.AppendLine(property.GetValue(obj, null).ToString());

        builder.AppendLine("</td>");
        builder.AppendLine("</tr>");
    }
}
```

Which also helps leave out all the properties that hasn't been set which again helps to reduce code.

However property.Name quite rightly outputs the name of the property in its current form

```
public string PropertyA { get; set; }
```

So the Email would look like

```
PropertyA : 123
```

Which doesnt look friendly to the user. So is there a way I can change the property name to display something different?

I have tried

```
[DisplayName("Property A")]
public string PropertyA { get; set; }
```

which should look like in the email:

```
Property A : 123
```

But to no prevail.... Is there anything out there to help on the road of the logic I am going down?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [find the attribute and extract the Name value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637679/reflection-get-attribute-name-and-value-on-property):

```
var displayNameAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes
                                    (typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false)
                                    .FirstOrDefault() as DisplayNameAttribute;

string displayName = displayNameAttribute != null 
                         ? displayNameAttribute.DisplayName 
                         : property.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks, the same as I said for the first answer, its not `attribute.Name` its `attribute.DisplayName` well for me...

Comment: Thanks, fixed. The `GetCustomAttribute<>()` extension method proposed by @Selman22 has a somewhat nicer syntax though.

Comment: In a way I agree, but you do the null check within a :? operator, however, I am not that picky to be honest, I can award the answer to @Selman22. I just normally award it on whom answers first but both of your answers are basically the same..

Answer (score 2):

You need to get `DisplayNameAttribute` of your property and then get it's `Name`:

```
var attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>();

if(attribute != null)
{
   var displayName = attribute.Name;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! However for me, its not `attribute.Name` its `attribute.DisplayName`