# Extract Description Attribute from Const Fields

Tags: c#, reflection

[Base on This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637679/reflection-get-attribute-name-and-value-on-property/32501356#32501356), I can get description attribute from class `Property` as follow:

```
public class A
{
    [Description("My Property")]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I can get `Description` value, as follow:

```
// result: My Property
var foo = AttributeHelper.GetPropertyAttributeValue<A, string, DescriptionAttribute, string>(x => x.MyProperty, y => y.Description);
```

and now, **What changes** Must I do in this helper to get description from `cosnt` `fields` as follow:

```
public class A
{
    [Description("Const Field")]
    public const string ConstField = "My Const";
}

// output: Const Field
var foo = AttributeHelper.GetPropertyAttributeValue<A, string, DescriptionAttribute, string>(x => x.ConstField, y => y.Description);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting value of objects const field by reflection:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public static class AttributeHelper
{
    public static TOut GetConstFieldAttributeValue<T, TOut, TAttribute>(
        string fieldName,
        Func<TAttribute, TOut> valueSelector)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var fieldInfo = typeof(T).GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        if (fieldInfo == null)
        {
            return default(TOut);
        }
        var att = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as TAttribute;
        return att != null ? valueSelector(att) : default(TOut);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
public class A
{
    [Description("Const Field")]
    public const string ConstField = "My Const";
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = AttributeHelper.GetConstFieldAttributeValue<A, string, DescriptionAttribute>("ConstField", y => y.Description);

        Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want use this helper that give me intellisense for my class, and use generic benefits.

Comment: @Amir modified example added to my previous answer.

Comment: With your modification, compiler error: cannot be accessed (`Id` is `const`) with an instance reference.

Comment: Just forgot that const field is a static one... take a moment i will fix it

Comment: @Amir modified helper API, now you can see how it works.

Comment: @Amir I changed the way of getting FieldInfo as we cant directly get const fields of objects. We must provide a field name as can't generate Expression for this item.

Comment: I've refactored the example a bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94026/discussion-between-andrii-tsok-and-amir).