# How to get description attribute from static field in C#

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have a class like this

```
public class AppFlags
{
    [Description("title")]
    public static bool ShouldRemoveTitle = false;
}
```

I want to get the description attribute value "title" of field ShouldRemoveTitle. How to do that as a fast way.

I saw a solution here but it must copy field name "ShouldRemoveTitle" as parameter, which make function is too hard to use
[Extract Description Attribute from Const Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485932/extract-description-attribute-from-const-fields)

Comment: Then just create a wrapper function that passes the name, so you don't have to pass it as a parameter? It's not clear why the linked question wouldn't answer your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract Description Attribute from Const Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485932/extract-description-attribute-from-const-fields)

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as on any other field. Just with the BindingFlag set to static

```
var attribute = typeof(AppFlags)
   .GetField("ShouldRemoveTitle", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
   ?.GetCustomAttribute<DiscriptionAttribute>(true);
string text = attribute?.Description;
```

Comment: I would like any method that just call AppFlags.ShouldRemoveTitle.GetDescription()

Comment: you should be able to build a (static)method around this one line of code. You can give it the name AppFlags_ShouldRemoveTitle_GetDescription() if you like.