# Custom Attribute on property in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-properties

I have a class Person with two properties

```
public sealed class Person
{
[Description("This is the first name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[Description("This is the last name")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In my console application code I'd like to get for each property of each instance the value of the Description Attribute.....

something similar to

```
Person myPerson = new Person();
myPerson.LastName.GetDescription() // method to retrieve the value of the attribute
```

Is it possible to do this task?
Can someone suggest me a way?
Best regards
Fab

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637679/reflection-get-attribute-name-and-value-on-property

Comment: With that syntax no, it isn't possible. With other syntaxes it is possible (as shown for example in the linked question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With exactly that syntax it isn't possible. It is possible by using Expression Trees... For example:

```
public static class DescripionExtractor 
{
    public static string GetDescription<TValue>(Expression<Func<TValue>> exp) 
    {
        var body = exp.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (body == null) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("exp");
        }

        var attrs = (DescriptionAttribute[])body.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true);

        if (attrs.Length == 0) 
        {
            return null;
        }

        return attrs[0].Description;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Person person = null;
string desc = DescripionExtractor.GetDescription(() => person.FirstName);
```

Note that the value of `person` is irrelevant. It can be `null` and everything will work correctly, because `person` isn't really accessed. Only its type is important.

Answer (score 3):

The `.LastName` returns a string, so you can't do much from there. Ultimately, you need the `PropertyInfo` for this. There are two ways of getting that:

- via an `Expression` (perhaps `SomeMethod<Person>(p => p.LastName)`)
- from a `string` (perhaps via `nameof`)

For example, you *could* do something like:

```
var desc = Helper.GetDescription<Person>(nameof(Person.LastName));
```

or

```
var desc = Helper.GetDescription(typeof(Person), nameof(Person.LastName));
```

with something like:

```
var attrib = (DescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
    type.GetProperty(propertyName), typeof(DescriptionAttribute));
return attrib?.Description;
```

Comment: Well, taking into account that nameof is available since C# 6.0 only.

Comment: @Alexey I did use the word "perhaps" ;)