# C# Override DisplayAttribute vs LabelFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I initially have used the answer to one of my [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618565/c-sharp-html-helper-extend-existing-method-without-overriding/37619770#37619770) as a helper to override the LabelFor methods. While it was doing exactly what I wanted, it did not satisfy the objective of **"automatically modify functionality over the entire project without going through every page to add extra parameters"** (**, "*"** for each LabelFor line in my case).

What I am thinking currently is either modifying LabelFor **without** adding extra parameter at the end, OR modifying the DisplayAttribute from DataAnnotations **without** renaming it and using my class name instead of Display.

When I tried to do LabelFor without adding extra parameter (again, refer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618565/c-sharp-html-helper-extend-existing-method-without-overriding/37619770#37619770)), no matter what I did, debugger automatically stepped out LabelFor without ever going into my LabelFor method, and was using default LabelFor.

When I tried Modifying DisplayAttribute , it only did what I wanted when I changed it from Display to myDisplay.

I used various sources, and I was getting mixed results, so I will ask here: **Is there any way to modify/override either LabelFor or DisplayAttribute WITHOUT adding new parameter or renaming method respectively?**

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Short answer is no.

Comment: What do you mean by *override display*.  I'm unfamiliar with a method called `Display()`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I mean like this **[Display(Name = "Year")]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. In order to use method with the same name, it must have different parameters. Or just rename the method and use it from now on.