# Simpler way of accessing custom attributes?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I have a property of the "Form1" class called "InfoTest" that has some custom attributes that I want to access.

The code works fine, but is a bit unwieldy:

```
[Test("foo",15)]
    public double InfoTest { get; set; }

    public void RetrieveAttribute()
    {
        PropertyInfo field_info = typeof(Form1).GetProperty("InfoTest");
        object[] custom_attributes = field_info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false);
        TestAttribute thisAttribute = (TestAttribute)custom_attributes[0];
        Debug.WriteLine(thisAttribute.Info + "," + thisAttribute.TheValue);
    }
```

I presume the answer is "No", but is there a simpler way of getting the attributes for InfoTest, that doesn't involve the `typeof(Form1).GetProperty("InfoTest")?  I can't go (for example):

```
    var runtimePropInfo = InfoTest.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties();
    var propInfo = InfoTest.GetType().GetProperties();
```

...Which is essentially because it is trying to get the properties of a "double", not a "InfoTest" object.

Comment: I do not think there is any simpler way, [as this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6637710/6741868) also shows, the solution you're currently using seems to be the optimal one already.

Comment: You can simplify it a little bit by using `TestAttribute thisAttribute =  field_info.GetCustomAttribute<TestAttribute>(false);`.  That cuts out the `object` array and the cast, but you still need the `PropertyInfo` (actually its base class `MemberInfo`) for the extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just relying on built-in functions, you can simplify it a bit by using [an extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138307(v=vs.110).aspx) on `MemberInfo` that can directly return a custom attribute.

```
PropertyInfo field_info = typeof(Form1).GetProperty("InfoTest");
TestAttribute thisAttribute = field_info.GetCustomAttribute<TestAttribute>(false);
Debug.WriteLine(thisAttribute.Info + "," + thisAttribute.TheValue);
```

That gets rid of an `object` array, and a type-cast.

If you are willing to use a custom extension method, you can use this one to simplify it to one function call. It has the benefit of being strongly typed, though it may not be as performant.

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute, TClass>(this TClass target, Expression<Func<TClass, object>> targetProperty) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression) targetProperty;
        var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression) lambda.Body;
        string name = ((MemberExpression) unaryExpression.Operand).Member.Name;
        MemberInfo info = typeof(TClass).GetProperty(name);

        return info.GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>(false);
    }
}
```

It can be used on anything (it's an extension of `object`) like this:

```
var attr = thing.GetAttribute<TestAttribute, Thing>(obj => obj.InfoTest);
```

It gets the `TestAttribute` from the `InfoTest` property of `thing`, which is an instance of the `Thing` class.

`Thing` is defined as:

```
public class Thing
{
    [Test("foo", 15)]
    public double InfoTest { get; set; }
}
```