# Is there any way to create dynamodb table with the data models classes using AWSSDK in asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I want to create a table in dynamodb using data model / entity classes. Is there any way to do in the way?

I have searched for the examples of table creation using entity classes but no results found

If you have any demo solutions or any documentation, please provide

Comment: Does this documentation help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-intro.html#dynamodb-intro-apis-object-persistence

Comment: Hi Joe, I have gone through this documentation; Here they provided to save or load the data in already created tables. There is no mentioning of creation of table

Comment: There's nothing out of the box.  You could write code to read attributes such as DynamoDBTable, DynamoDBHashKey from your models and call the AWS API - but the model won't generally contain all the information you need to create the table - e.g. Provisioned throughput.

Comment: Note also that you will often want different table names for Development and Production environments: any code that creates the table will therefore need to know what prefix to prepend to the table name you retrieve from the DynamoDBTable attribute:  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/configuring-dynamodb-tables-for-development-and-production/.

Comment: Sure, will follow the suggestion you have given, @Joe

Answer (score 0):

For creating table based on models, there are two steps.

First, you need to get the table name, AttributeDefinition and KeySchemaElement from entity, for this, you could try reflection to get the entity attibute and properties like [Reflection - get attribute name and value on property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637679/reflection-get-attribute-name-and-value-on-property/6637710).

Second, you could try create table based on above information like [Step 2: Create a Table Using the Low-Level API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NET.02.html)

Comment: I am using the reflection to get the properties of the model. To define the AttributeDefinition list, what value to provide in ScalarAttribute type?

Comment: @Raghavendraprasad What do you mean by `ScalarAttribute`? What is your current model and what is your expected value?

Comment: I have found ScalarAttributeType is the datatype for the primitive elements such as B, S, N, BS etc