# How do I compare two different data in one table using Blazor?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, blazor

Problem solved:
Instead of using two dynamic lists, only one list is needed:

```
ObeservableCollection<dataClass> currentList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<dataClass>();
```

The dataClass stays the same, so does the TelerikGrid. See code below.

The CompareData() function is changed.

```cs
public string CompareData(string? SportsName)
{
   if (currentList.Count > 1)
   {
      var i = currentList[0];
      PropertyInfo? obj = i.GetType().GetProperty(SportsName);
      string s = (string)obj.GetValue(i);

      var i1 = currentList[1];
      PropertyInfo? obj1 = i.GetType().GetProperty(SportsName);
      string s1 = (string)obj1.GetValue(i1);

      if (s != s1) 
      {
         return "red";
      }
      else
      {
         return "";
      }
   }
   else
   {
       return "";
   }
}
```

This solution uses [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789138/reflection-blazor-get-attribute-name-value). There could be a better solution but this works for me.

---

Ouestion:
I have two dynamic lists right now

```
ObeservableCollection<dataClass> currentList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<dataClass>();
```

and

```
ObeservableCollection<dataClass> previousList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<dataClass>();
```

and my dataClass looks like this:

```
public class dataClass
{
   public string FullName { get; set; }
   public int SportsId { get; set; }
   public string SportsName { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

I have a table using TelerikGrid which shows all the data from currentList. what I am trying to do is to have a cell in the TelerikGrid highlighted when the data in that cell is changed. For example, a person with the same name could be registered in multiple sports so when that happens, only the sportsId and sportsName cells get highlighted.

Using TelerikGrid

```
<Template>
   var a = context as dataClass;
   var SportsName = instance.SportsName;
   <div class="@CompareData(SportsName)">@instance.SportsName</div>
</Template>
```

I can use a function in my razor.cs file to do it and I've tried to pass the SportsName from the Telerik Grid into the function but am unsure how to get it right.

```
public string CompareData(string? SportsName)
{
   string? currentSportsName = SportsName;
string? prevSportsName = **idkwhattoputhereorhowtodoit**;

   if (currentSportsName != prevSportsName) 
   {
      return "red";
   }
   else 
   {
      return "";
   } 
}
```

My main issue is getting the data from the previousList and using it for comparison.

Comment: Will update this post with the latest approach. This approach doesn't work as the logic is somewhat flawed.