# Set Property of Instance without Setter

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Suppose I have a class and an interface that looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass : IClass
{
   public int Prop => 42;
}

public interface IClass
{
   int Prop { get; }
}
```

As you can see there's no Setter. But I was hoping to use reflection to change the Prop property but I can't seem to do it. Here's what I have so far:

```
var property = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Prop", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
property.SetValue(instaneOfClass, 31);
```

I keep getting this error: `System.ArgumentException: Property set method not found.`

Shouldn't this work? How can I set the property without using a setter?

Comment: I closed it as duplicate of earlier suggested answer as it already contained text "complex code". I've also edited the answer to add "complex code includes `int TheAnswer => 42;` so it clearly answer this one too.

Comment: The mystery that remains is: Where is that int of value '42' stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auto implemented properties have backing fields named `<PropName>k__BackingField`.

In your case you would access this backing field like this:

```
var property = typeof(MyClass).GetField("<Prop>k__BackingField", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
property.SetValue(instanceOfClass, 31);
```

Note that I'm calling `GetField()` instead of `GetProperty()`, and using `BindingFlags.NonPublic` instead of `BindingFlags.Public`, since the backing field is private.

**However, since this is an expression bodied member (lambda syntax), no backing field is generated.** Instead of relying on another member, the getter simply returns the result of the given expression, and the compiler doesn't need to generate a backing field.

Implementing your property with an explicit getter will generate a backing field, and the above code will work.

```
public class MyClass : IClass
{
   public int Prop { get; } = 42;
}
```

Comment: [Display(Name = "# Items")]
        public decimal ITEMS { get; set; }

How to get type from DisplayName ?

Comment: @KrunalShah Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6637679/1951064

Answer (score 2):

If you specify a getter you'll have a compiler generated field that contains the property name. You can then modify the value of this field using reflection (GetFields, SetValue):

```
public class Foo        {
        public Foo() => Bar = 42;
        public int Bar { get; }        

        static void Main()  {
           var f = new Foo();
           Console.WriteLine(f.Bar); // ==> 42;
           f.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).First(x => x.Name.Contains("Bar")).SetValue(f, 43);
           Console.WriteLine(f.Bar); // ==> 43;
  }
}
```

It does not work for a computed property as in your example.