# C# reflection get all property information inside the proerperties with custom attribute

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, reflection, attributes

I am writing a method for extracting all properties from an object (including properties of its own) with custom attribute . For example

```
  public class SomeModel
{

    [Custom]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public string TestData { get; set; }

    [Custom]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

   public  InnerModel InnerModel { get; set; }
}
```

And Inner Model :

```
  public class InnerModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = "TestID";

    [Custom]
    public string Year { get; set; }

    public ThirdObject HidedObject { get; set; }
}
```

And the third  one  :

```
 public class ThirdObject
{
    [Custom]
    public string  HidedName { get; set; }
}
```

I need to find all properties with "Custom" attribute .
Testing :

```
SomeModel model = new SomeModel()
        {
            Name = "farid",
            Surname = "Ismayilzada",
            TestData = "Test" ,
            InnerModel = new InnerModel() { Year ="2022" , HidedObject= New ThirdObject{ HidedName="Secret"}}
        };
```

I need to write the method

```
GetMyProperties(model) => List<PropInf>()
[PropertyName= Name,Value=Farid ,Route="Name" ]
[PropertyName= Surname,Value=Ismayilzada,Route="Surname" ]
[PropertyName= Year,Value=2022,Route="InnerModel.Year" ]
[PropertyName= HidedName,Value=Secret,Route="InnerModel.HidedObject.HidedName" ]
```

How to get this information ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/accessing-attributes-by-using-reflection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reflection - get attribute name and value on property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637679/reflection-get-attribute-name-and-value-on-property)

Comment: @Ibrennan208 nope . I need to get all property name ,value and path from the object . There must be some recursive approach .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a method like this :

```
private static IEnumerable<PropInfo> GetPropertiesInfo(object obj, string route = "")
{
    List<PropInfo> results = new List<PropInfo>();

    // You can filter wich property you want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=net-6.0
    var objectProperties = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead);
    foreach (var property in objectProperties) 
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(obj);

        if (property.PropertyType.IsClass && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
        {
            results.AddRange(GetPropertiesInfo(value, route + property.Name + "."));
        }
        else
        {
            // Check if the property has the Custom Attribute
            var customAttributes = property.GetCustomAttributes<CustomAttribute>();
            if (!customAttributes.Any())
                continue;
            // You can set a method in your Attribute : customAttributes.First().CheckIfNeedToStoreProperty(obj);

            results.Add(new PropInfo()
            {
                PropertyName = property.Name,
                Value = value,
                Route = route + property.Name
            });
        }

    }

    return results;
}

public class PropInfo
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }
}

public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool CheckIfNeedToStoreProperty(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```