# StringLength in ViewModel not setting maxlength on textbox

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Here the property in my ViewModel:

```
[Display(Name = "Ext.")]
[MaxLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Must be a maximum of 6 characters")]
[StringLength(6)]
public string Extension { get; set; }
```

And in my View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Extension)
```

And it renders:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Ext. must be a string with a maximum length of 6." data-val-length-max="6" id="Extension" name="Extension" type="text" value="" />
```

Should this be setting the maxlength attribute on my textbox? If not, how can I do that with DataAttributes?

Comment: Have you verified if you can post a string longer than 6 characters?

Comment: I do get a validation error, but I want it to actually set the maxlength attribute.

Comment: If you change it to `TextBoxFor` you can pass in HTML options.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like the attribute that I set in the ViewModel to control this if possible.

Comment: If you are using `unobtrusive validation` this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9710021/1551730) could be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I'd like the attribute that I set in the ViewModel to control this if
>   possible.*

ASP.NET MVC provides an extensible system for doing exactly this. Here is what you need to do:

1. Implement a custom `ModelMetadataProvider`.
2. Look for the `StringLengthAttribute` or the `MaxLengthAttribute`, extract the information and add it to the `ModelMetadata`.
3. Provide a custom Editor template that makes use of the information.

**Step 1:** Implement a custom `ModelMetadataProvider`.

Create a class that derives from `ModelMetadataProvider`. Typically you would derive from the `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` as this provides some default functionality which means you only have to override a single method called `CreateMetadata`.

**Step 2:** Extract the information:

To get the information, you need to look for the attribute, extract the maximum length information and add it to the `AdditionalValues` dictionary of the `ModelMetadata`. The implementation would look something like this (this is the entire implementation):

```
public class CustomModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, 
        Type containerType, 
        Func<object> modelAccessor, 
        Type modelType, 
        string propertyName)
    {
        // Call the base class implementation to create the default metadata...
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(
            attributes, 
            containerType, 
            modelAccessor, 
            modelType, 
            propertyName);

        // Extract the stringLengthAttribute (you can do the same for the
        // MaxLengthAttribute if you want).
        var attr = attributes
            .OfType<StringLengthAttribute>()
            .First();

        // This could be getting called on a property that doesn't have the
        // attribute so make sure you check for null!
        if (attr != null)
        {
            metadata.AdditionalValues["maxLength"] = attr.MaximumLength;
        }

        return metadata;
    }
}
```

In order for ASP.NET MVC to use this you need to register it in the `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax`.

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomModelMetadataProvider();
```

**Step 3:** Create a custom editor template.

You now need to create a view that uses the information. Create a new view called `String` in the `Views\Shared\` folder.

**String.cshtml**

```
@{
    object maxLength;
    if (!ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues
            .TryGetValue("maxLength", out maxLength))
    {
        maxLength = 0;
    }

    var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        {"class", "text-box single-line"},
        { "maxlength", (int)maxLength },
    };
}

@Html.TextBox("", ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, attributes)
```

When you run your application you will get the following HTML output by calling `@Html.EditorFor`.

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Extension" maxlength="6" name="Extension" type="text" value="" />
```

If you want to know more about the model metadata provider system, [Brad Wilson has a series of blog posts](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) that detail how it works (these were written prior to the Razor view engine so some of the view Syntax is a bit funky but otherwise the information is sound).

Comment: Benjamin, you are a machine today!

Answer (score 5):

Essentially based on Brad's answer, wrapped in an extension on the Html helper using lambda syntax so you don't pollute your Razor views with reflection stuff:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class HtmlHelper
{
    public static int? MaxLength<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;

        PropertyInfo property = typeof(TModel)
            .GetProperty(memberExpression.Member.Name);

        StringLengthAttribute attribute = (StringLengthAttribute)property
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), true)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (attribute != null)
        {
            return attribute.MaximumLength;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Use it like such:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { maxlength = Html.MaxLength(x => x.Name) })
```

where `x` refers to your model.

If the `StringLengthAttribute` is not declared for the property, `null` will be returned and the `maxlength` attribute will be empty on the textbox element.

Remember to include using in your razor page so you can access the method.

```
@using HtmlHelper
```

You also need to use none null-able result for the method to overcome compile error.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into something similar, here was my quick and dirty solution:

at the top of your .cshtml file add the line:

```
@{
var max = ((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute)(typeof(MyType))
.GetProperty("MyProp")
.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute), true)[0]).MaximumLength;    
}
```

below that in your html replace the EditorFor with:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Extension, htmlAttributes: new {maxlength=max })
```

I eventually decided I'd rather just do it in script:

```
<script>
    $(function ()
    {
        var max = $("#myinput").attr("data-val-length-max");
        $("#myinput").attr("maxlength", max);
    });
</script>
```

but if you don't want to to add script the first example should work.

Comment: This code works, but you might want to keep your Razor views cleaner using something like a helper. See my answer for an example of that.