# How to limit filed length in razor template with type number?

Tags: html, razor

I tried this one, but not working

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.discount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @step = "0.01", @min = "1", @max = "99999" } })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `maxlength` and a `TextBoxFor` instead of `EditorFor`

`EditorFor` has no overload that permit to do that.

This could be even more interesting for you :
[maxlength attribute of a text box from the DataAnnotations StringLength in Asp.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386365/maxlength-attribute-of-a-text-box-from-the-dataannotations-stringlength-in-mvc2)

Answer (score 1):

**@minlength="10",@maximumlength="10"**
*u can use textboxfor or editorfor
anything will work......*